# django can't resolve attribute name

Tags: django

Can anyone see the source of this error?

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'client' into field. Choices are: auditstatushistory, file_num, invoice
```

The statement that is causing the problem is:

```
for invoice in Invoice.objects.filter(matter__client__servicer_code = "XXX"):
```

And the definition of Matter, which does contain file_num, and auditstatushistory and invoice as related attributes, is :

```
class Matter(models.Model):
    file_num = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey("Client", db_column="client_code", 
                               related_name="client")
```

the only "odd" thing in here is that client did not exist as a foreign key when I set up the database originally, so I added client_code to the underlying matter table via

```
alter table foo_matter add client_code varchar(10) null;
```

And there is no foreign key in the database linking client and matter.  The only thing I can think of is that I did not name the column correctly in my foo_matter table.  But I can't run syncdb to try it out because South has been installed.

UPDATE:

Just for giggles, I tried starting with a brand-new database, commented out South, and just did a "syncdb" to see what table definitions Django would create.  It created the Client and Matter tables, but did NOT create client_code (or client_id) field to store the foreign key information.

Has anyone seen a situation like this, where Django just does not create a field?

Comment: Two points of confusion here. One, if you're using South, why didn't you add the client foreign key via a migration? Two, if you're adding the field fresh, why are you breaking convention by calling it 'client_code' instead of 'client_id' and having to specify `db_column` as a result?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using South while I'm in development, as I sometimes change my mind about database designs (and column names!), and then I have to clean up the migrations.  Client_code already existed in the Client table (to match some other systems), and I'm trying to keep things consistent.

Comment: I built a quick test case on another Django system without South and found that I did name my tables correctly.

Comment: and if I stop the code in a debugger, grab a matter, and interrogate "matter.client" or "matter.client.servicer_code" I get the correct answers

Comment: if you don't want to use south, just comment out the south app in your settings.py. In your quick test case on the fresh django system, are you getting the same errors?

Comment: can you post your Invoice code, and a pastebin a full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaaah!  The problem was that I had a property (with a getter) defined further down in the class named "client".  That was a leftover from an earlier iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a wild guess, and say that the code you have right now and the fields in the database simply don't match. If you are not using south during development, the only way to make changes to the database is either by hand, or just dropping the changes tables and re-running syncdb. At the beginning of the design stage you can do that, but its really really recommended to use south, specially once you have data that you just can't drop.